# ssh-copy-id asking for password & ssh closing

Tags: ssh, docker, containers, centos6, ssh-keys

I'm currently deploying a Centreon server on 2 docker containers. (One for central server and one for the Poller)
The 2 containers are runnning CentOS 6.7

When runnning :

```
$ ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_rsa.pub centreon@adress
```

I always have :

```
The authenticity of host 'address (address)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is xx.xx.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'address' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
centreon@address's password:
```

I should also have

```
Now try logging into the machine, with "ssh 'centreon@address'", and check in:

  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

to make sure we haven't added extra keys that you weren't expecting.
```

But I don't
Tried some things to solve this.

1)
.ssh/ has drwx------ acccess
.ssh/id_rsa and .ssh/id_rsa.pub both have -rw-r--r-- access

2)
in

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

the options :

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys
```

are activated.

I noticed that .ssh/authorized_keys isn't created.

What could be the issue ?

**EDIT :**

`ssh centreon@address`

prompts for password and then returns :

`connection to address closed`

`ssh centreon@address -v -v -v -v` result :

```html
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to address [address] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /var/spool/centreon/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /var/spool/centreon/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /var/spool/centreon/.ssh/id_rsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /var/spool/centreon/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /var/spool/centreon/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /var/spool/centreon/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /var/spool/centreon/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /var/spool/centreon/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /var/spool/centreon/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: Wrote 960 bytes for a total of 981
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug3: Wrote 24 bytes for a total of 1005
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 131/256
debug2: bits set: 505/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug3: Wrote 144 bytes for a total of 1149
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host address filename /var/spool/centreon/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host address filename /var/spool/centreon/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 1
debug1: Host 'address' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /var/spool/centreon/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 517/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: Wrote 16 bytes for a total of 1165
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug3: Wrote 48 bytes for a total of 1213
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /var/spool/centreon/.ssh/identity ((nil))
debug2: key: /var/spool/centreon/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f4139c52a30)
debug2: key: /var/spool/centreon/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /var/spool/centreon/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug3: Wrote 64 bytes for a total of 1277
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-keyex
debug3: remaining preferred: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-keyex
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug3: Trying to reverse map address address.
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Cannot determine realm for numeric host address

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Cannot determine realm for numeric host address

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Cannot determine realm for numeric host address

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /var/spool/centreon/.ssh/identity
debug3: no such identity: /var/spool/centreon/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /var/spool/centreon/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 368 bytes for a total of 1645
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /var/spool/centreon/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /var/spool/centreon/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /var/spool/centreon/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /var/spool/centreon/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
centreon@address's password: 
debug3: packet_send2: adding 48 (len 61 padlen 19 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 144 bytes for a total of 1789
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug3: Wrote 128 bytes for a total of 1917
debug2: callback start
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env HOSTNAME
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env HISTSIZE
debug3: Ignored env QTDIR
debug3: Ignored env QTINC
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env MAIL
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env HISTCONTROL
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env QTLIB
debug3: Ignored env CVS_RSH
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env G_BROKEN_FILENAMES
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: Wrote 448 bytes for a total of 2365
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Last login: Wed May  4 15:43:59 2016 from address
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cc -1)

debug3: channel 0: close_fds r -1 w -1 e 6
debug3: Wrote 32 bytes for a total of 2397
debug3: Wrote 64 bytes for a total of 2461
Connection to address closed.
Transferred: sent 2264, received 2192 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 265256.1, received 256820.4
debug1: Exit status 254
```

Comment: Of course `ssh-copy-id` prompts for a password...presumably you are using it to install a public key on the remote host, which means the remote host does not yet have an `authorized_keys` file.  Authenticate with your password, allow `ssh-copy-id` to install the public key, and subsequent connections should work without a password.

Comment: Well, I can't remember ever having to enter a password for `ssh-copy-id`. And of course that I already authenticate, (didn't mentioned it, sorry) but `.ssh/authorized_keys` isn't created. and btw, after authenticating, I should have a little text saying to verify .ssh/authorized_keys to check if it has not added extra key, but here I don't have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PAM Authentication was causing trouble.
commenting `usePAM yes` and everything goes right.

Thanks Ra_ for making me stay more on the sshd_config file.

Answer (score 1):

Your private key .ssh/id_rsa must be readable only by yourself.

```
$ chmod 700 $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Then

```
$ ssh-copy-id <user>@<host>
```

Comment: That changed nothing.

Comment: Something changed: After adjusting id_rsa permissions you can use id_rsa to authenticate, not before. By the way, you are using /var/spool/centreon/.ssh/id_rsa, so double check you adjusted the right file.

Comment: I meant on the result. Right file edited, but I don't think that the problem comes from the rights on the key, because a classic `ssh user@host` would work. that's not the case.

Comment: Understood. Check /etc/ssh/sshd_config for "PasswordAuthentication yes"

Comment: No `#` before `PasswordAuthentification yes`